# PIP install not working Debian

Tags: python, python-2.7, debian

I am setting up a new server and python is not installing correctly for any modules.  This is debian 8, and I cant seem to get this to work.  I am not sure if its an SSL issue or something else is going on.

Anyone have any ideas?

```
$ pip install paramiko
Downloading/unpacking paramiko
Cleaning up...
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 290, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1178, in prepare_files
    url = finder.find_requirement(req_to_install, upgrade=self.upgrade)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 194, in find_requirement
    page = self._get_page(main_index_url, req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 568, in _get_page
    session=self.session,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 694, in get_page
    req, link, "connection error: %s" % exc, url,
TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type Error)


$ pip install XlsxWriter
Downloading/unpacking XlsxWriter
Cleaning up...
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 290, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1178, in prepare_files
    url = finder.find_requirement(req_to_install, upgrade=self.upgrade)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 194, in find_requirement
    page = self._get_page(main_index_url, req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 568, in _get_page
    session=self.session,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 694, in get_page
    req, link, "connection error: %s" % exc, url,
TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type Error)
```

EDIT: Here is what happens whey I try and run the get-pip script.

```
tmp$ python get-pip.py
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:581) - skipping
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

Comment: did you make it work finally?

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
cd /tmp
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
python get-pip.py
rm get-pip.py -f
```

then :

```
python -m pip install paramiko XlsxWriter
```